# windows visual studio CTRL + . for mac

Tags: windows, flutter, macos, dart, command

I am at the stage of learning flutter over video. In the video, the windows user performs an operation with the command "CTRL + . ", when I do this on my mac computer with "command + . ", there is no result. What is the equivalent of this command in windows on mac computers?[image]

Comment: Did you install flutter extensions for vs code???

Comment: yes i uploaded flutter extensions

Answer (score 2):

it called `Refactor` on `VSCode`

you can customize the shorcut from:
`File`>`Preferences`>`Keyboard Shorrcuts`.

by default the keyboard shortcut is :

- `Ctrl+Shift+R` (windows)
- `Ctrl+Shift+R` (mac)

or you can `Right click` on the Widget and `Refactor`